# Overriding constructor of Element interface in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, overriding

I would like to set id attributes for all the DOM elements by default. The **IMPORTANT** point is that it should happen during the construction of elements (when the browser is parsing HTML code and creating HTML elements and before appending them to the DOM tree). For example, if the HTML code of my website is like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
  //overriding constructor of Element
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id='nH6Rf72Jk'> This is a paragraph </p>
  <p> This is another paragraph </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to have an id attribute (a random value) even for elements that do not explicitly an id has specified for them. I think it might be possible by overriding constructor of the Element interface (by the script that exists in the head). In other words, while browser is generating the elements and appending them to the DOM tree, check the id attribute; if it doesn't exist, generate a random value and set it as the id. Does anyone know if is possible to override the Element constructor? Or is there any other solution for this problem?

Comment: can you explain why you need this "feature"? Maybe your real Problem can be solved otherwise

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```js
let all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (let i=0; i < all.length; i++) {
    if(all[i].getAttribute('id') === null){
      all[i].setAttribute('id', makeId(6));
    }
}

function makeId(length) {
   let finalStr           = '';
   let chars       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
   var charsLength = chars.length;
   for (i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      finalStr += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charsLength));
   }
   return finalStr;
}
```

Comment: You'd want to check if the element has an id first, so that you don't replace it. Other than that it looks ok

Comment: What if new elements are added to the DOM on the fly? I'd suggest using a `MutationObserver` and device a strategy for the later.

Comment: No, it doesn't solve my problem. In my problem, the solution should add the id to the element during the construction of elements and before being appended to the DOM.

Comment: @nxbit you can call the makeId function, like if you have created the element named ele, then you can set it's id like `ele.setAttribute('id', makeId(6))` while creating the element and before appending it to the DOM

Comment: @TalmacelMarianSilviu I have updated the code, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: My question is for the elements that are generated by the browser, not by javascript. For example in the snippet that I have in the question, there are two <p> tags, my problem is adding an id to this element before being appended to the DOM. That is why I am mentioning to override Element interface constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll('body *');
  elements.forEach((elem => {
    if (!elem.getAttribute('id')) {
      elem.setAttribute('id', btoa(window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0]));
    }
  }));
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a solution to my problem. Please read the question again.

Comment: Well, this is to answer the "Or is there any other solution for this problem?" of your question.

Comment: I mean "any other solution" to set the id attribute before being appended to the DOM.
If your solution sets the id after that, it doesn't help. Thanks for your comment by the way.